# Xcode 9 background fetch scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, background, fetch, xcode9

In order to test background fetch in the Xcode 8 simulator, we could duplicate our current build scheme and in the "Run->Options" pane tick the box saying "Background Fetch ☑️ Launch due to a background fetch event".

I can't find this in Xcode 9. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Actually I've just found the answer to my own question.

Looks like we don't do this any more. Just build the app normally, then from the Xcode debug menu select "Simulate Background Refresh".

Comment: you know, its kinda dumb, but checkbox "Launch due to a background fetch event" is still there and its not working. I mean, strange error "iPhone has denied the launch request" is popping, event if provisions are ok. (Un)checking "Debug executable" in run configuration does not have an effect. BUT simply running app and then selecting Debug->Simulate background fetch, and its ok then.

So thanks for the answer, it helped.